# conditional style on button in html table

Tags: html, django

I am using a for loop to display data inside a table.

my html code:

```
<tbody>
    {% for deal_id, deal_name, deal_status in deals_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{deal_id}}</td>
        <td><a href="/deal_data?deal_id={{deal_id}}&vendor_id={{vendor_id}}">#{{deal_id}}</a></td>
        <td>{{deal_name}}</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" disabled="true">{{deal_status}}</button></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

currently i am using class `btn btn-success` for all the deal status.
I want when deal_status is `'ACTIVE'`,  `btn btn-success` must be used.
if deal_status is `'INACTIVE'`, `btn btn-danger` must be used.
How to do that?

Comment: Which templating language is this?

Comment: i am using django as my backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the if-else blocks to control only the conditional output, which is the button class

```
<button type="button" class="btn 
    {% if deal_status == 'ACTIVE' %}
        btn-sucess
    {% else %}
        btw-danger
    {% endif %}" disabled="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<tbody>
{% for deal_id, deal_name, deal_status in deals_list %}
<tr>
    <td>{{deal_id}}</td>
    <td><a href="/deal_data?deal_id={{deal_id}}&vendor_id={{vendor_id}}">#{{deal_id}}</a></td>
    <td>{{deal_name}}</td>
    <td>{% if deal_status.INACTIVE %}<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" disabled="true">{{deal_status}}</button>{% else %}<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" disabled="true">{{deal_status}}</button>{% endif %}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It changed all the status' class to `btn-danger`